# How I can delete views in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'd like to add to my app functionality that is similar to the known `View.INVISIBLE`, `View.GONE` from the `.xml`. Is there any "elegant" way to achieve it? I have a simple `column`, with let's say one `Text`. When some conditions are meet, I'd like to delete it, to save memory, and space for other views. How I may achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`mutableStateOf`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/package-summary#mutableStateOf(kotlin.Any,androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotMutationPolicy)) and toggle it whenever you want.

```
var shouldShowText by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
```

For example, a simple example would be :

```
@Composable
fun DeleteViewComposableExample() {
    var shouldShowText by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }

    if (shouldShowText) {
        Text("Skizo-ozᴉʞS ツ rules")
    }

   
    Button(onClick = { shouldShowText = !shouldShowText }) {
        Text("Change state")
    }
}
```

With this you can Show/Hide `@Composable`s

Other way is if you are using `StateFlow/SharedFlow` you can update the state and add a parameter in the state class as `textVisible: Boolean` and then when updating it, depending on the `Boolean` show or not the `Text` and then here you do not need the `mutableStateOf`.

Comment: Thank you for the help, but I'd like to ask - does example provided by you, managing visibility, or also can delete the view?

Comment: There's no "delete view" it's render or not render, that's different in Compose than xml